# jQuery prevent execution of function on a page

Tags: jquery, function, return

I have a "global" script called `global.js` which is included on the header of the page.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#ajax_loading').html('<div><img src="load.gif" /></div>');
    $('#ajax_loading').show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#ajax_loading').hide();
});
```

On `this_page.js` I've tried

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    return;
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    return;
});
```

or

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

but the `global.js` functions are still executed.

Now on a page I want that those two functions (ajaxStart and ajaxStop) aren't executed on ajax calls. How can I solve the problem?

`global.js` is included before `this_page.js`.

Comment: Is there anything else inside global.js?

Comment: Yes another function which is not used on that page

Comment: Then why do you need to include that script file on that page? Why not just leave it out?

Comment: I believe he means it is a global script i.e. to be included on every page

Comment: This script is included on the header, so if I include the header the script also comes in.... Maybe in the future I'll add more function that will be used on this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` simply attach another handler. To truly disable the handler you must call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    global: false
});
```

before your ajax code.